# Gantt chart reduce horizontal spacing between blocks

Tags: gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

Am new to Gantt chart and facing some issues between the block in horizontel view .
Say i have 3 block , block 1 start time is at 5 and end time is 10 and block 2 start time is at 10 and endtime is at 15 and **block 3 starttime is at 100 and endtime is at 105**.

if you notice the above data , block 1 and block 2 are in sequence , but block 3 is located far away from block 2

Is there a way i can reduce the gap between block2 and block3 horizontelly ?
We cant manually edit the time of block3 , since there will be number of blocks and we are not sure about it .

So is there a way i can reduce the gaps between the block in horizontel in gantt chart ?

Comment: No.  A Gantt chart has a horizontal axis of time.  If block 3 starts at day 100, it will start on the Gantt chart at day 100.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc got your point , but is there a way i can reduce the gap between block2 (whose end time is 15 ) and block3 (whose start time is 100). is there away i can SHRINK/ RELATIVELY REDUCE the gap between these 2 blocks ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc since there is lot of white space between these blocks and no need of that , of course on click of each block we are showing the exact data , hence visually if we can reduce the white space between blocks , will be great